# How to put a cite in the same line with a figure title?

Tags: urls

[image: code]
Excuse me, I'm not able to put the cite url **[4]** on the same line with the figure title "Cycle de vie de la donnée".[image: data cycle]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please explain your issue better. Can you add a short compilable tex code resulting in your issue?

Comment: Instead of putting codes as images, please post the codes directly...

Comment: @Mensch, I just edited my post by adding the code. Thanks

Comment: Also, always post `MWE` from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`

Comment: You've added an image of the code, not the code itself.  We can't copy and paste an image.  And because you've not included everything from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`, we'll get errors about `\includegraphics`, `\captionof`, and `\citeurl`.  We can make reasonable guesses about the first two of those, but `\citeurl` is new to me.

Comment: You are right, I tested it and got errors. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

[image]

You only need to insert `\cite` inside caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\includegraphics{example-image-duck}
\captionof{figure}{Cycle de vir fr la donnee \cite{?}}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below:

```
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=off]{caption}

\begin{document}
```